# Three player mahjong: flower as dora

Tags: mahjong

We didn't have a fourth player for some time so we switched from riichi to three player version with korean\japanese rules as described on [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_player_mahjong) (I guess that's the most popular version for 3 players).

Used to doras in riichi we played with one [revealed dora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_player_mahjong#Revealed_Dora_Tiles). But I didn't find there what do do if a flower tile is revealed as dora.

Shuffling whole set again in this case seems too much so we decided that every flower sholds add one more bonus point. Is this right or is there some other commonly used rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I commonly flip over the next tile. (following the procedure in HK-style where if a player draws a flower, it is revealed and a replacement tile drawn)

Comment: Thanks! It's a bummer to lose a flower that way, but this indeed sounds like a more solid way than ours.